# Proof Verification: Prove X and Y are open sets

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

The exercise was to show that the following two sets are open given $G$ is a region and $f$ is holomorphic in $G$.

$ X = \{a \in G \text{: there exists } r>0 \text{ such that }f(z)= 0 \text{ for all } z\in D[a,r]\}$

$ Y = \{a \in G \text{: there exists } r>0 \text{ such that }f(z) \ne 0 \text{ for all } z\in D[a,r]\backslash \{a\}\}$

My proof did not use the fact that $f$ is holomorphic, so I fear there is a flaw somewhere. Here is my attempt at proving this.

Let $x \in X\cap \partial X$. Since $x \in X$, we know there is $r>0$ such that for all $z \in D[x,r], f(z)=0$. Similarly, since $x\in\partial X$, for all $R>0$ there is some $z \in D[x,R]$ such that $z\notin X$. In particular, there is $z^*$ in $D[x,r]$ such that $z^* \notin X$. Choosing $\delta = \text{min}\{|x-z^*|, r-|x-z^*|\}$, we know $f(z) \ne 0$ for some $z \in D[z^*, \delta]$ and $D[z^*,\delta] \subset D[x,r]$. But this contradicts $f(z)=0$ for all $z\in D[x,r]$, showing $X \cap \partial X = \emptyset$, meaning $X$ is open.

Let $y \in Y$. Then there is $r>0$ such that $f(z) \ne 0$ for all $z \in D[y,r] \backslash \{y\}$. Pick $a \in D[y,r] \backslash \{y\}$. Let $\epsilon = \text{min}\{|y-a|, r-|y-a|\}$. Then $f(z) \ne 0$ for all $z \in D[a, \epsilon]$ because $D[a,\epsilon] \subset D[y,r] \backslash \{y\}$. So $a \in Y$, meaning $D[y,r] \subset Y$, so $Y$ is open.

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ are open for any function $f$.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. Perhaps the extra assumption was a carryover from the proof this exercise was a part of. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This looks correct to me! Maybe as an intuition, let's consider just $Y$. Let $S=\{z\in \mathbb C\mid f(z)\neq 0\}$. Notice that this proof holds if $G$ and $S$ are ***any sets***. Then
$$
Y=\{a\in G\mid \text{there exists }r>0\text{ such that }D[a,r]\setminus \{a\}\subseteq S\}
$$
For any $y\in Y$, such an $r$ exists. Then let $\epsilon=\frac{r}{2}$, so for any $a\in D[y,\epsilon]$ where $a\neq y$, there exists $r'=\frac{|y-a|}{2}$ such that $\big(D[a,r']\setminus\{a\}\big)\subseteq \big(D[y,r]\setminus \{y\}\big)\subseteq S$, so this means $a\in Y$. Therefore $D[y,\epsilon]\subseteq Y$, so $Y$ is open.

Notice my notation, how the epsilon accompanies $y\in Y$, and the $r'$ accompanies the particular $a$ in the $\epsilon$-disk.

Comment: Ah okay. Perhaps that assumption on $f$ is just a leftover from the main proof this came from. Thanks!